# reflecting a mySQL boolean in a checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a field in mySQL featured, TINYINT, which will be either 0 or 1

I also have a form:

```
      <input type="checkbox" name="featured" value="<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['featured']; ?>"/><br /><br />
```

When I select the checkbox I am able to set the value to '1' in mySQL, however not the other way round because when I view the update record page the checkbox is always blank (I understand the checkbox status is independent of the value and should be set so).

I therefore need the checkbox to be checked if value '1', and also if I uncheck, then I need the value in mySQL to change back to '0'

I know there are lots of posts on this, but I can't seem to make head nor tail, and nothing I try works.

Can we keep it in PHP please?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use it in your html checkbox:

```
<?php if ($row_rs_dealItem['featured'] == 1) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>
```

and write it in your file where you save the data:

```
if(isset($_POST['featured'])) $featured = 1; else $featured = 0;
```

Comment: According to my code editor, there is a syntax error in your second line?

Comment: aha missing ) after square brackets

Comment: Still doesn't show a tick :( - definitely putting the first line in the value bit?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['featured']; ?>" <?php if ($row_rs_dealItem['featured'] == 1) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13507/discussion-between-pete-norris-and-shehzad-bilal)

Answer (score 2):

```
$featured = (isset($_POST['featured'])) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use PHP's `intval` function,
after you submit the form, in the file where you save the data:

```
$_POST['featured'] = intval($_POST['featured']);
```

If checkbox isn't checked $_POST['featured'] is NULL, and `intval(NULL)=0`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['featured']))
{
    $_POST['featured'] =1;
}
else
{
   $_POST['featured'] =0; 
}
```